# Removing quotes in String Array in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am new to bash scripting and trying to get rid of quotes in my string array output.

```
DATABASES=(demo_db1 demo_db2);

for DB_NAME in “${DATABASES[@]}”; 
do
    echo ${DB_NAME}
done
```

Output:

```
“demo_db1

demo_db2

demo_db3”
```

How can I ignore the quotes in the output?

I will use it in my DB connection string so it gives me so much trouble in the example below.

```
for DB_NAME in “${DATABASES[@]}”; 
do
    connection_url="postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@localhost:5432/${DB_NAME}/"
    echo $connection_url
done
```

Output:

```
postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@localhost:5432/“demo_db1/

postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@localhost:5432/demo_db2/

postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@localhost:5432/demo_db3”/
```

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: Replace all `“` with `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `”` which you have used in `”${DATABASES[@]}”` in the for loop. You need to use `"`.
Try the following script:

```
DATABASES=(demo_db1 demo_db2);

for DB_NAME in "${DATABASES[@]}"; 
do
    echo ${DB_NAME}
done
```

Output :

```
demo_db1
demo_db2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove '"' chars using sed:

```
echo $(echo ${DB_NAME} | sed 's/["“”]//g')  # all flavour of quotes
```